# Where can I find the list of all offers and their offer IDs?

Tags: azure, azure-billing-api

I was trying to get all offers and their offer ID's from [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/offer-details/). However, I have an offer `Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN`, which was updated to `Visual Studio Enterprise with MSDN (benefit)`. However, when I try to query all my subscriptions, what I get as the display name for my subscription is:

`"displayName": "Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN",`

which isn't listed as an offer (not even in the list of updated and retired offers).

Is there a place where I get the list of all offers and their offer IDs?

**N.B.:** I have filed [an issue](https://github.com/Azure/BillingCodeSamples/issues/17) regarding the same on their github page.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because concerns services offers, and not programming.

Comment: @Renzo: This isn't a concern per se, there can be documentation which I have missed out. It can be concern or a bug if there really isn't any which  cannot be ruled out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to fetch the list of offers programmatically, unfortunately there's none. However you can view the list of all Azure offers here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/offer-details/.

Also, currently it is not possible to find the Offer Id associated with an Azure Subscription programmatically. You would need to find this information manually by logging into Azure Portal.

Comment: Yes, but even that site doesn't list all the offers. For eg, `Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN` isn't listed either in the current or retired offers even though you'll get this offering as the display name for your subscription which has now been updated to `Visual Studio Enterprise with MSDN (benefit)`

Comment: I believe you're confusing Subscription name with Offer Id. They are two different things. What do you see when you login into Azure Portal and check subscription details. That's where you will see Offer Id.

Comment: If I am not wrong, what you see [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/offer-details/) as the offer name is what you should see as `display name` when you query for subscriptions, right? If yes, then as I said earlier `Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN` comes up as the `display name` for one of my subscriptions, but isn't listed on the page mentioned above. If not, then yes, I am confusing offer name with subscription name.